# sqlite - use a column field in a limit clause

Tags: sqlite

using sqlite, I'm trying to run a query with a limit clause, but instead of specifying a literal I am trying to use a column. Sadly I am getting an 'no such column' error. Is there a way of achieving what I mean without writing an external program?

Example

```
select * from ep where code=2 limit code
```

Comment: To what row do you refer column?

Comment: Per @JohannesKuhn comment I don't see how this could work since it wouldn't resolve to a single value.

Comment: assume it does, assume there is only one row such as "code = 2"

Comment: If you are explicitly filtering on `code=2`, why can't you explicitly `limit 2`?

Comment: it's an example, tried to make it simple but I confused matters by using code in both sides, let's say "limit field"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM ep WHERE code = 2 LIMIT (SELECT code FROM ep WHERE ...)
```

Please note that the subquery must return a single value (if it returns multiple records, only the first one is used).

Comment: the problem is that when I join inside the subquery with a field from the outer query it doesn't recognise it

Comment: @ ArturoP you need to alias the table outside the query so you can reference it inside the subquery, like so: `SELECT * FROM ep e1 WHERE code = 2 LIMIT (SELECT code FROM ep e2 WHERE e1.val = e2.val ...)`

Comment: done it, doesn't work either it comes back with 'no such column e1.val'

Comment: @ArturoP You cannot join or correlate the subquery because the `LIMIT` value is applied to the entire result of the outer query afterwards. What is your actual goal?

Comment: so, I have two tables, one master with itemID and a number n and another detail with several rows in general for every itemID sortable by date (another field), what I want is a query that, for each itemID in the master table returns the n most recent rows in the detail table for that itemID (n, is in general different for each itemID). thanks!

Comment: This is not possible with `LIMIT`. Make this comment a real question.